# Using CKAN API to create employee lookup tool in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, api, ckan

I am trying to create an employee lookup tool that displays the name and extension of a person. The input is a field that people can start typing a name and it shows the name and the phone extension. I am using a CKAN api to access the dataset.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#search-box").keyup(function(){

   var data = {
       resource_id: '3ef94617-bc46-4f4c-840d-8872c211dce9',
       q:$(this).val()
    };  
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://data.open.guelph.ca/api/action/datastore_search",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: "true",
        callback: "jquery",
        data:data,
        success: function(data){
            var html = [];
            $.each(data.result, function(index, d){            
            html.push(JSON.stringify(d,['Contact Name','Phone Extension'] , null, "<br>") );
            });
            $("#matches").show();
            $("#matches").html(html);
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I can get an output but it is in JSON format. I have tried using the syntax:

```
d["Contact Name"]
```

instead of JSON Stringify but it doesn't work! I believe it may be the dataStore api but I do not know of an alternative.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solutuon!

Adding the records array seemed to do the trick eg.

```
data['results']['records']
```

So the code now looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#search-box").keyup(function()                      

    var data = {
       resource_id: '3ef94617-bc46-4f4c-840d-8872c211dce9',
       q:$(this).val()
    };  
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://data.open.guelph.ca/api/action/datastore_search",
        type: "get",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        cache: "true",
        callback: "jquery",
        data:data,

        success: function(data){
            var html = [];

            $.each(data['result']['records'], function(index, d){            
            html.push(d['Contact Name'],"  " , d['Phone Extension'] , "<br>");
            });
            $("#matches").show();
            $("#matches").html(html);
        }
    });
});
});
```